# Decide what dll to call at runtime

Tags: c#, interface, process.start

I am using the `Process.Start()` method to launch a specific executable as needed. The executable is tailor-made, there are many of these, and the paths & names are in the database together with the job they do.

Is there another way to launch them in-process, if they all implement an interface? I want to be able to debug them and have better type safety when calling them.

I can set a library project in each solution, then instantiate that library and have it do the job instead of the executable. The question is about a mechanism that would allow me to build against the interface then load the library by its name at runtime.

Comment: Kind of sounds like you want a plugin based application.

Comment: Google C# and reflection. That will allow you to load assemblies from file and query for info on types and interfaces as well as many other things.

Comment: Look into MEF.  Otherwise, consider a dependency injection container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like the following if you want custom solution. Otherwise, you can use modular patterns implemented in [Prism with Unity or MEF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg406140.aspx).

```
public interface IPlugin
{
    void Start();
}

// You can change this to support loading based on dll file name
// Use one of the other available Assembly load options
public void Load(string fullAssemblyName)
{
    var assembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(fullAssemblyName);

    // Assuming only one class implements IPlugin 
    var pluginType = assembly.GetTypes()
               .FirstOrDefault(t => t.GetInterfaces()
               .Any(i=> i == typeof(IPlugin)));

    // Concrete class implementing IPlugin must have default empty constructor
    // for following instance creation to work
    var plugin = Activator.CreateInstance(pluginType) as IPlugin;
    plugin.Start();
}
```

Comment: Would this work as a fullAssemblyName: @"C:\Code\Development\Executable 1\Launcher\bin\Debug\Launcher.dll"

Comment: loopdecode, thank you for the answer but I was not able to use it.  I get a FileLoadException.  Still playing around but any suggestions are welcome.  Thanks.

Comment: You will need to use fully qualified namespace of the assembly if you are using the example. If you want to load file directly, then you can use Assembly.LoadFrom(filename) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1009fa28(v=vs.110).aspx