# How can I dynamically load classes from another project within Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: c#, wcf, visual-studio-2012

I'm developing a WCF service that uses an interface (not the ServiceContract interface) to perform some internal work.  My goal is to extend the functionality of this service after deployment by delivering New DLLs with classes that implement this interface (and corresponding web.config updates).

I'm starting with just one class that implements the interface.  In my solution, I have the Service in one project (WCF Service Application) with the interface definition, and the class that implements the interface in another project (Windows Class Library).

I am using the following code to dynamically load the class (based on a parameter passed when the service is called):

```
InterfaceFoo af = (InterfaceFoo)System.Activator.CreateInstance(AssemblyQualifiedName, ClassType).Unwrap();
```

When this line is called, I get a FileNotFoundException, Could not load file or assembly.

I believe the above code is correct, as I have it working at runtime from a separate proof of concept project once it's built and deployed, and the DLL is placed in the same folder as the EXE.  I believe my problem is related to how I've referenced the projects, or the variables I'm passing to the CreateInstance() method when run within Visual Studio.

What I've tried and I still get the same error: In the WCF Service Project I've set the Class Library project as a reference.  In the WCF Service Project I've added a link to the interface implementing class.

I'm wondering if the values I'm using for  AssemblyQualifiedName and ClassType won't work within Visual Studio since they aren't yet deployed?

Any advice is appreciated, even if you think a completely different approach is better.

ADDED AFTER INITIAL POST:
I had an idea after posting, I moved the interface implementing class from the Class Library Project to the WCF Service Project.  When I do this, it works.  That to me eliminates the assembly and type parameters as issues, and the issue is that I'm not linking correctly to the Class Library Project.

Comment: I answered a similar question few days ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24557849/decide-what-dll-to-call-at-runtime/24558322#24558322

Comment: I looked at your post, but I'm not sure how to apply that to my situation.  My code works when deployed, but I can't seem to get a good reference at development time within Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

You can move your interface defenition to another shared library (dll) and then use it.